# How to make box plots for two types of samples using percentiles in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a data that looks like this:

```
df <-data.frame(
  Group = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), 
  GOOD_0 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
  GOOD_25 = c(61.25, 1, 1, 1), 
  GOOD_50 = c(119, 1, 1, 1), 
  GOOD_75 = c(153, 1, 1, 1), 
  GOOD_100 = c(237L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
  SALINE_0 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
  SALINE_25 = c(1, 40.25, 1, 22.5), 
  SALINE_50 = c(1, 86, 52.5, 122.5), 
  SALINE_75 = c(1, 136, 101.5, 269.25), 
  SALINE_100 = c(60L, 360L, 222L, 508L)
)
```

I want to plot box plot for both GOOD and SALINE types one after another (perhaps in two different colors). Numbers after GOOD_ and SALINE_ indicate their percentiles. How can I make box plot for `Groups` using these percentiles in R?

I can do for GOOD types like this, but couldn't include SALINE boxes in the same plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Group, ymin = GOOD_0, lower = GOOD_25, middle = GOOD_50, upper = GOOD_75, ymax = GOOD_100)) +
      geom_boxplot(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: in `aes(x=x...)` what is `x`?

Comment: @Croote Opps, that was Group. I have edited the question.

Comment: I thought, so, I have posted a response, its mostly got to do with data shape, you can use reshaping methods to achieve the same thing that I brute forced but your column names being all different makes it a bit trickier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you transform your data a little you can do this easily. The best way to deal with `ggplot` is to have your data in long format. So rejigging your `dataframe` to look this way, and adding a column which identifies which group `SALINE` or `GOOD` it belongs to.

I am assuming your x variable is `Group` since `x` doesnt exst in the data as your have done with `aes(x=x ...)`

```
GOOD <- df %>% select(Group, starts_with("GOOD")) %>% rename(Percentile_0 = GOOD_0, 
                                                     Percentile_25 = GOOD_25, 
                                                     Percentile_50 = GOOD_50, 
                                                     Percentile_75 = GOOD_75, 
                                                     Percentile_100 = GOOD_100) 
SALINE <- df %>% select(Group, starts_with("SALINE")) %>% rename(Percentile_0 = SALINE_0, 
                                                       Percentile_25 = SALINE_25, 
                                                       Percentile_50 = SALINE_50, 
                                                       Percentile_75 = SALINE_75, 
                                                       Percentile_100 = SALINE_100) 


new_df <- bind_rows(GOOD %>% mutate(grp = "GOOD"), SALINE %>% mutate(grp = "SALINE"))

new_df
# A tibble: 8 x 7
  Group Percentile_0 Percentile_25 Percentile_50 Percentile_75 Percentile_100 grp   
  <fct>        <int>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>          <int> <chr> 
1 1                1          61.2         119            153             237 GOOD  
2 2                1           1             1              1               1 GOOD  
3 3                1           1             1              1               1 GOOD  
4 4                1           1             1              1               1 GOOD  
5 1                1           1             1              1              60 SALINE
6 2                1          40.2          86            136             360 SALINE
7 3                1           1            52.5          102.            222 SALINE
8 4                1          22.5         122.           269.            508 SALINE
```

Now there are a few ways to have done what I did above. but once that is done, plotting both is very straightforward and `ggplot` will create a legend for you if you specify a `colour` aesthetic. Hence,

```
new_df %>% ggplot(aes(x = Group, group = grp, colour = grp)) +
           geom_boxplot(stat = "identity", 
                        aes(ymin = Percentile_0, lower = Percentile_25, middle = Percentile_50, upper = Percentile_75, ymax = Percentile_100))
```

Final Data frame

```
structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), Percentile_0 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Percentile_25 = c(61.25, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 40.25, 1, 22.5), Percentile_50 = c(119, 1, 1, 1, 1, 86, 52.5, 
122.5), Percentile_75 = c(153, 1, 1, 1, 1, 136, 101.5, 269.25
), Percentile_100 = c(237L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 60L, 360L, 222L, 508L
), grp = c("GOOD", "GOOD", "GOOD", "GOOD", "SALINE", "SALINE", 
"SALINE", "SALINE")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Not sure why I am getting this error for using rename: `Error in rename(., Percentile_0 = SALINE_0, Percentile_25 = SALINE_25,  : 
  unused arguments (Percentile_0 = SALINE_0, Percentile_25 = SALINE_25, Percentile_50 = SALINE_50, Percentile_75 = SALINE_75, Percentile_100 = SALINE_100)`

Comment: Have you changed the code at all, I have just run it again straight off your data provided and it works. might specify `dplyr::rename`

Comment: I have just added the `dput` from my results for the `new_df`

Comment: it works now. Not sure why R packages were not loading properly. Thanks for your help.